# Clojure Tic Tac Toe solver

Tags: clojure, tic-tac-toe

I am going through the 4clojure problems and I currently just solved the [Tic Tac Toe analyzer](http://www.4clojure.com/problem/73#prob-title):

```
(fn [board]
    (let [vr (for [x (range 3)]
              (get-in board[(+ x 0) (+ x 0)]))
          vl (for [x (range 3)]
               (get-in board [(+ x) (- 2 x)]))
          columns (apply map vector board)
          checks (concat board [vl] [vr] columns)]
      (letfn [(check-board [[row & res]]
                (if row
                  (let [dist (distinct row)]
                      (if (or (= dist [:o]) (= dist [:x]))
                        (first dist)
                        (check-board res)))
                  nil))]
        (check-board checks))))
```

I'm looking for any feedback about how I could make the code more terse.

Could I have created the diagonal vectors in one expression?

I don't like that I had to use recursion but I could not think of a way of using something like reduce because I don't think there is a way to short circuit reduce if you find the result midway through processing all the values.

Is there a way that I could avoid recursion with this problem?

Comment: Once you have solved a 4Clojure problem, you can look at others' solutions. Top users' solutions can teach you a lot, though some tend to be a bit code golfy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Some Minor Points

`(+ x 0)` and `(+x)` can be replaced by just `x`, in `(get-in board[(+ x 0) (+ x 0)]))` and `(get-in board [(+ x) (- 2 x)]))` respectively.

You can omit the `nil` in else position in `if` : `(if row ... nil)` \$\rightarrow\$ `(if row ...)`

Idiomatic way of checking if something is one of a number of things is using a set of those values as a predicate: `(or (= dist [:o]) (= dist [:x]))` \$\rightarrow\$ `(#{[:o] [:x]} dist)`

Rename `row` to something not misleading. Since you named the collection `checks` you could name the iteration variable `check`.

### Your Questions

> Could I have created the diagonal vectors in one expression?

Yes. If you factor out the differing portions, namely `[x x]` and `[x (- 2 x)]`, you get:

```
(let [diagonals (for [f [#(list % %) #(list % (- 2 %))]]
                  (for [x (range 3)]
                    (get-in board (f x))))
```

Since `diagonals` is already a sequence, you replace
`checks (concat board [vl] [vr] columns)]` with `checks (concat board diagonals columns)`

> Is there a way that I could avoid recursion with this problem?

Recursive processing of collections/sequences can be straightforwardly transformed to [`for`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/for) expressions. Your :

```
(letfn [(check-board [[row & res]]
                (if row
                  (let [dist (distinct row)]
                      (if (or (= dist [:o]) (= dist [:x]))
                        (first dist)
                        (check-board res)))
                  nil))]
        (check-board checks))))
```

becomes this:

```
(first 
  (for [row checks 
        :let [dist (distinct row)] 
        :when (or (= dist [:o]) (= dist [:x]))]
    (first dist)))
```

Note `for` is lazy, therefore `(first (for ...` is equivalent to your short-circuit return.

### These Changes Applied Altogether

```
(fn [board]
  (let [diagonals (for [f [#(list % %) #(list % (- 2 %))]]
                    (for [x (range 3)]
                      (get-in board (f x))))
        columns (apply map vector board)
        checks (concat board diagonals columns)]
    (first 
      (for [check checks 
            :let [dist (distinct check)] 
            :when (#{[:o] [:x]} dist)]
        (first dist)))))
```

### Final Point

Also check out [`some`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/some), [`every?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/every_q), [`keep`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/keep), etc. which process collections with a predicate; and which this exercise probably wants you to learn. For example `some` is probably what you mean by *short-cut evaluation `reduce`*.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for taking the time to do this.  Great points!

Answer (score 1):

Stimulated by your question, I've had another go at solving this.

> Could you have created the diagonal vectors in one expression?

Yes. See below.

> Is there a way that you could avoid recursion with this problem?

Yes. The problem is not properly recursive. You can use the sequence functions to

- generate the lines,
- scan through them, and
- to scan each line if need be (avoided below).

And, by the way, there is now the [`reduced`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduced) function which allows you to exit a `reduce`.

---

The idea is to do it in two stages:

1. From the given `rows`, generate the columns and the diagonals, hence
   all the lines.
2. Test each line in turn to see if it is purely `:x`s or purely `:o`s.
   If so, that's the answer.

Hopefully, whatever we use to run through the lines will return `nil` if it doesn't find a solving one.

```
(defn ttt [rows]
  (let [cols (apply map vector rows)
        diags (map #(map % (range 3)) [#((rows %) %) #((rows %) (- 2 %))])
        lines (concat rows cols diags)]
    (first (some (comp #{#{:x} #{:o}} set) lines))))
```

---

I now see that [@abuzittingillifirca's solution](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/63126/43360) exploits all the techniques employed here, though preferring `for` to `some` and `map`.